# Close all collapsible content at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight) {
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.content    {
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">First question</button>
<div class="content">First answer</div>

<button class="collapsible">Second question</button>
<div class="content">Second answer</div>

<button class="collapsible">Close all collapsible content</button>
```

There are two collapsible buttons called `First question` and `Second question`. You click on one of them to show the content and you click again to hide the content.

If you opened multiple collapsible contents you have to click on each of them to close all. I need a button that allows to close all at once.

But I don't know how to tell the javascript code not to close only one but every content.

Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: why so difficault instead of toggeling a class in CSS? Easiest way would be to use `querySelectorAll('.content')` which will return a Node-List. Then you can use `forEach` to manipulate all elements of the Node-List at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would delegate

```js
const collapse = (elem,forceClose) => {
  const content = elem.nextElementSibling;
  if (!content || !content.matches(".content")) return; // no content after the element, so leave
  if (forceClose) elem.classList.remove("active"); // passed force or nothing passed
  else elem.classList.toggle("active");
  content.style.maxHeight = elem.classList.contains("active") ? content.scrollHeight + "px" : null;
};

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches(".collapsible")) return; // clicked on something not a button
  if (tgt.matches(".all")) { // special button
    const close = container.querySelectorAll(".collapsible.active").length > 0;
    buttons.forEach(but => collapse(but,close)); 
  } else {
    collapse(tgt);
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
.active { color: green; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="collapsible">First question</button>
  <div class="content">First answer</div>

  <button class="collapsible">Second question</button>
  <div class="content">Second answer</div>

  <button class="collapsible all">Toggle all collapsible content</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But there's a bug. If some are open and some are closed and you click on `Toggle all collapsible content` all open will close and all closed will open. But instead I want to close or open all of them. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Thanks. But now you can only close them with `Toggle all collapsible content`. Clicking on e.g. `First question` to close it doesn't work any more.

Comment: Ok, solved now. Try again

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code you provided, you should just need to loop through all of your divs with the class `content`. From there you can apply the same `maxHeight` styling you do with the individual buttons.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight) {
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    });
}

function _CollapseAll() { document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(el => {
    el.style.maxHeight = null;
});
}
```

```css
.content    {
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">First question</button>
<div class="content">First answer</div>

<button class="collapsible">Second question</button>
<div class="content">Second answer</div>

<button class="collapsible" onclick="_CollapseAll()">Close all collapsible content</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to use `querySelectorAll('.content')` which will return a Node-List. Then you can use `forEach` to manipulate all elements of the Node-List at once:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight) {
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    });
}

//closes all collapsibles
document.querySelector('.collapsible-all').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(el => el.style.maxHeight = null);
})
```

```css
.content    {
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">First question</button>
<div class="content">First answer</div>

<button class="collapsible">Second question</button>
<div class="content">Second answer</div>

<button class="collapsible-all">Close all collapsible content</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract your commands to collapse or expand an item into functions, to be able to reuse them.

Then you simply reuse your `coll` variable and pass all items from `coll` to your `collapse()` function.

You should give the *Collapse All* button another class to not include it in the group of elements to close.

The following code uses some more modern features like [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and most importantly [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) because it allows to use the quick [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of counting i’s.

Also, to render the collapsible elements accessible for people with disabilities, who rely on assistive technology, I added ARIA attributes that indicate the state of the collapsible. See the [Disclosure Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/) if you want to know more.

```js
// expand a collapsible
const expand = button => {
  const content = button.nextElementSibling;
  button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
  content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
  content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 'px';
};

// close a collapsible
const collapse = button => {
  const content = button.nextElementSibling;
  button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
  content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
  content.style.maxHeight = null;
}

const coll = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');

// implement each collapsible
coll.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.classList.toggle('active')) {
      // now it’s expanded (active)
      expand(btn);
    } else {
      // now it’s collapsed
      collapse(btn);
    }
  })
});

// close all collapsibles on button click
document.querySelector('.collapsible-all').addEventListener('click', () => {
  coll.forEach(btn => collapse(btn));
});
```

```css
.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="first-answer">First question</button>
<div class="content" id="first-answer">First answer</div>

<button class="collapsible" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="second-answer">Second question</button>
<div class="content" id="second-answer">Second answer</div>

<button class="collapsible-all">Close all collapsible content</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to be able to also open all of them with a button click?

Comment: Sure, since now you have two functions, you can simply pass all coll elements to the expand function: `coll.forEach(btn => expand(btn))`. It’s the same as for the collapse all button.